# Workflows don't work, canceled by System Account

Tags: workflow, nintex

I am using Nintex workflow in SharePoint. Lately, whenever someone runs a workflow (eg. travel request, leave request..etc) they get a message saying workflow was canceled by System Admin. 
After some dig up I have seen that database is not connected, in event viewer it says : cannot open database "WSS_Content"requested by login.
Any idea how to fix this?